# Log transformed variable and main effect

Tags: regression, data-transformation, nonlinear-regression

I'm dealing with linear regression with a continuous outcome. Due to suspected non-linearity in one of the covariates (via scatterplot) I tried some possible transformations of the independent variable. Using the AIC as criterion, I have two models that seem suitable:

Model 1:
$$
Y =\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 X^2
$$

Model 2:
$$
Y =\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 \log X
$$

I stumbled on model 2 more by accident, since I was trying to do a log-transformation but I forgot to exclude the main effect.

Both models give me a better model fit (based on AIC), but the fit with model 2 is even better than that of model 1 (the difference in AIC is quite big). I also tried a log-transformation of $X$ without the untransformed $X$-Term, but that gave me no improvement compared with the original model without transformation.

Is it ok to have $\log X$ as well as $X$ in the model? I don't see a reason why it would be a problem, but I've never encountered this situation before. Hence, I'm not quite sure. Additionally, I'm also not sure how to interpret such a model in terms of the effect of $X$.

Edit:
Here the scatterplot with fitted curves superimposed. Model 3 refers to the model with $log(X)$ only.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a plot of predicted vs observed values, with the mean regression line superimposed, for each model?

Comment: Combining x and log x as predictors has been standard for some time in various fields. One heading is "fractional polynomials". See for example http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rfp.pdf and the references it cites.

Comment: Note, however, that neither model mentioned here features a transformation of the dependent variable. So, either you have a typo, or you are alluding to yet other models you tried.

Comment: The scatter plot of $Y$ vs $X$ with fitted curves superimposed would be even easier to think about than a plot of observed and predicted.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, there was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for the graph. Model 3 looks poorest, but it's easy to be over-impressed by how well or poorly it does for the top 5% or 10% of the $X$s. The choice between Model 1 and Model 2, and any others, should draw upon which kind of curve matches ideas about what the relationship should be as well as just fit for this data set. I'd expect the plot of $Y$ versus $\log X$ with fitted curves to be another one to try.

Comment: I would also check the assumptions of the model and whether either model 1 or model 2 violates them.

Comment: I've seen such models; for example, when Y has also been log-transformed it corresponds to modelling the original variable by a scaled gamma density. (In physics such models - a product of a power term and an exponential term - may sometimes be called Hoerl curves.)

Comment: I guess it's implicit in the other comments, but the risk of over-fitting the data by accidentally finding a transformation that gives a better AIC is significant and it is unclear if this new model with log transformed variable adds significantly to your research question/objective.

Comment: @charles I agree with your main point, but note in passing that you are using words like "significant" in about two extra senses...

Comment: What is sensible limiting behaviour as $X$ goes to 0 or $X$ becomes very large is likely to be one of the key factors in deciding on the best model here. The implication of taking logs of $X$ is that $X$ must be positive. Nor is it evident that the best model will be linear, as @Glen_b also implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to have both in the model and quite common for non-linear relationships. Essentially, when you take logs you're looking at the proportional change in the variable rather than the level. In your model 2 the $\beta_2$ coefficient tells you the levels change in $Y$ for a proportional change in $X$. For example, $\beta_2 = 2$ means that a 1% change in $X$ increases the level of $Y$ by 2.

Comment: Clearly $X$ and $\log X$ are dependent, so the interpretation of the coefficient of either has to be more nuanced than this when both are included in the model. But it's easy enough to differentiate the right-hand side in this case.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification, that was careless of me.